# Altering codes by not using many loops for reading large datasets

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a simple way of making a dictionary for many different json files?
I wish to create a dictionary but also to consider the process time, for example, if I have 1 thousands of json files.

My current code:

```
#My current approach loop each file and then create a dictionary for the particular file. Since its looping so it will take much time if the files are too huge
# I would like to consider the huge file process time in making the dictionary and searching for another alternative to my current codes.

file = [[[json],[json],[json],[json],[json]]] #this is just an example of 5 json files for explanation and seeking help purpose. In real aim is to focus in 1000++ json files.

full_dic = {}
for i, f in enumerate(file): # this loop each file but what if I have thousands so it will take much time
    dictionary = {}
    for ii, fs in enumerate(f): # this loop each file sentence, even worse when have thousands f(file)
        **Here I will create my dictionary by reading the json file contents, this part does not matter because it depends on my json files, so can be ignored**
        **Finally, dictionary created like this**  
        dictionary[ii] = something
    full_dic[i] = dictionary
```

is there even a much more better way or time reducing way to perform this when having large datasets?

Comment: Store everything in a list instead of a dict and use the json module to do the parsing. SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: `multiprocessing` module may help to let multiple processes work on the files in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be one line (Assuming you have a list of json file path in `file` list):

```
my_dict = {i: json.load(open(file[i])) for i in range(len(file))}
```

Although if you should make sure that these 1000 json file fits in your memory first. It's also preferable to not name your variable `file`, as it's one of the default `__builtin__` in python.

Comment: I see, thank you so much. I will proceed to alter and try it.

Comment: Glad to be able to help.